Use Spring Authorization server without database
I want to use Spring Authorization Server with Federated Identity Providers.
I don't need Internal database in this case. Is it possible to disable it or skip configuration for database?

Are you only using it for initial authentication?

yes, I use a basic authentication.

I suppose it is possible to symetricly encrypt the federated providers refresh tokens and validate the refresh tokens by decrypting and delegating the token endpoint to the federated one.
